# warning when python access 2d list with None value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, warnings

I want to create a `n*n` list in python with most of the elements initialized with None. Then I will set some elements in a for loop, but in the line I set diagonal elements to be `0`, I got a warning highlight on `[j]` in PyCharm, saying:

> "Unexpected type(s): **(int, int)** Possible types: **(int, None)** (slice,
>   Iterable[None])  Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors
>   in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing,
>   this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of
>   function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3
>   function annotations."

I don't know where is wrong. If I change the 2d list to be all initialized as `0` in the first line, then this warning is gone. What makes `None` special here?

```
prev = [[None] * n for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i == j:
            prev[i][j] = 0
        ......
```

Comment: works like a charm in python 2.7

Comment: Your code works fine for me in `python 3.6.1`

Comment: work fine in `Python 3.5.5` and `Python 2.7.15` at Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I am using Python 3.6.1 with PyCharm Community Edition 2018.2 in Windows 10 x64

Comment: A similar error has [already been reported](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001811659-Not-sure-why-I-get-this-unexplained-type-error).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a warning, so your code should still run.

PyCharm tries to help you by telling what the type of variables should be, to help you to avoid error. However, **sometimes it gets it wrong**.

This feature is really useful in functions. For example:

```
def myfunction(x: str):
    return x

myfunction(1)
```

you should see the same warning above the `1`, because it is an `int` but the function expects a `str`.

In you case, the type is not explicit, so likely a misjudgment from PyCharm happens.

If you change the `None` from your code to a `1` or any other `int`, you that the warning is gone.

```
prev = [[1] * n for i in range(n)]
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i == j:
            prev[i][j] = 0
                    ^
                    |
              Warning gone
```

If you change the `None` to `'a'` or any other `str` you will see a similar warning but with `(int, str)` this time.